# Is my algorithm correct? (string concatenation)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Given a set S of m strings and a target string t we want to check whether or not t is the concatenation of some of the m strings while allowing repetition.
Example : S= {ab, dbe, eaa, ea} and t=eaabdbeab. Here the answer is YES, t=ea ab dbe ab.

Algorithm :

```
boolean IsConcatenation{S, t, i} { 
  int a=S[i].length;
  int b=t.length-1; 
  String str=t.charAt(1)+t.charAt(2)+...+t.charAt(a-1);`
  if (S[i]==str) { `    
    if (i<m)    //m=S.length
      boolean A= IsConcatenation(S,t, i++);  
    t=t.charAt(a)+t.charAt(a+1)+...+t.charAt(b);  
    boolean B= IsConcatenation(S,t, 0);
  }
  if (i==m+1)
    return false;
  if (t.length==0}
    return true;
  return IsConcatenation(S,t, i++);  
}
```

This is my pseudo code. I would be very grateful if you could tell me whether my algorithm is correct or no.

Thank you.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user93765 This doesn't make your question on-topic here. And the fact that a site is in beta won't stop people from answering your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not state any problem with the code.

Comment: @alex This doesn't belong on Code Review either, because user93765 doesn't say whether there is a problem with the code. It would be on-topic here if user93765 knew there _is_ a problem with the code, and it would be on-topic there if he knew that there is _not_ any problem with the code, but asking _if there is_ any problem with the code is not on-topic anywhere.

Comment: You have the right idea, but got many of the details wrong.

Comment: I guess the OP just wants to know if his code is correct but it quite ambiguous becuase he could he/she could be referring to conventional rules, whether code works or is there a shorter way or does his code fulfill what he wants to do.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat its a problem in the logic of the code not the code itself, I just want to make sure of the details.

Comment: @Henry details like what? you mean like boundary issues?

Comment: I want to know what boolean IsConcatenation{S, t, i} means.

Comment: So you know for a fact that there is a problem in the logic of the code?

Comment: @user93765 some indication of problems: the check `i<m` comes after accessing `S[i]`; you never use `A` and `B` after setting them; recursion should be stopped after a valid split has been detected; ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea looks correct but slow.

Some of the implementation details (for example, using `i++` instead of `i + 1`, and also possibly some off-by-one errors) are wrong, and I believe this is pseudocode, not code in any existing language.

To hint on a faster solution, consider solving the following set of subproblems: can a prefix of `T` of length `k` be represented as a concatenation of some strings from `S`? These can be solved with a dynamic programming approach for all `k` from `1` up to the total length of `T`. The largest of these subproblems is the actual problem we want to solve.

Comment: this is exactly what am searching for, i need to solve this using dynamic programming, if I write the code would you see it for me please?

Comment: Fine, though you would be better off if you mentioned that in the question.

Comment: do you know any website that let me understand dynamic programming? I am having difficulty understanding its concept. Thank you.